# How to add AP details without wifi?

Tags: wifi, pi-zero

I made a ghastly mistake. I hit the wrong key and purchased a Pi Zero instead of the Pi Zero W that I wanted.

I have a wifi dongle, but I can't attach it and the keyboard at the same time. I tried an old USB hub, but that didn't work. I suspect it's due to insufficient current.

Is it possible to edit `wpa_supplicant.conf` without the presence of wifi hardware and expecting it to work when I attach the wifi dongle later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obviously NOT create a wpa_supplicant.conf interactively, but you can make one manually - even on a PC.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

PS You would probably find the Pi Zero W rather limiting - it is well worth the few extra bucks to get a Pi3